# Javascript, HTML Distance Matrix API

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am trying to create an Google Distance Matrix API that accepts latitude and longitude then returns the proximity of cities. (i.e. the closest to the furthest)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map */
      #map {
        height: 400px;
        /* The height is 400 pixels */
        width: 600px;
        /* The width is 600 pixels */
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--The div element for the map -->
      <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // Initialize and add the map
      let map;

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 6,
          center: {
            lat: 41,
            lng: -86
          }
        });

        const cities = [{
            lat: 41.88,
            lng: -87.62
          }, // Chicago
          {
            lat: 43.05,
            lng: -87.95
          }, // Milwaukee
          {
            lat: 42.33,
            lng: -83.04
          }, // Detroit
          {
            lat: 39.76,
            lng: -86.15
          }, // Indianapolis
          {
            lat: 38.62,
            lng: -90.19
          } // St. Louis
        ];

        // Loop through cities, adding markers
        for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
          let position = cities[i]; // location of one city
          // create marker for a city
          let mk = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map
          });
        }



        // Add Distance Matrix here
        const service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService(); // instantiate Distance Matrix service
        const matrixOptions = {
          origins: ["233 S Wacker Dr, Chicago, IL 60606"], // technician locations
          destinations: ["41.8848274,-87.6320859", "41.878729,-87.6301087", "41.8855277,-87.6440611"], // customer address
          travelMode: 'DRIVING',
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
        };

        // put request on page
        /*         JSON.stringify(
                matrixOptions,
                null,
                2
                ); */

        // Call Distance Matrix service
        service.getDistanceMatrix(matrixOptions, callback);
        /*       JSON.stringify(
              response,
              null,
              2
              ); */
        // Callback function used to process Distance Matrix response
        function callback(response, status) {

          if (status !== "OK") {
            alert("Error with distance matrix");
            return;
          }
          console.log(response);
        }
        let routes = response.rows[0].elements;
        const leastseconds = 86400; // 24 hours
        let drivetime = "";
        let closest = "";

        for (let i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
          const routeseconds = routes[i].elements[0].duration.value;
          if (routeseconds > 0 && routeseconds < leastseconds) {
            leastseconds = routeseconds; // this route is the shortest (so far)
            drivetime = routes[i].elements[0].duration.text; // hours and minutes
            closest = response.originAddresses[i]; // city name from destinations
          }
        }
        alert("The closest location is " + closest + " (" + drivetime + ")");

      }

    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

The code is working fine up until the `console.log(response)`.

When I run the code, I get the correct `Distance Matrix Response` i.e. `status`,`origin_addresses`,`destination_addresses` and `rows` showing up on my console.

I am also running a `loop function` to get the code to arrange the cities based on their proximity.

I struggle with `callback functions` a lot. Can someone please help me define the `response` in the `callback function` to get the code to return the closest city to me?

Answer (score 0):

You have calculated the routes **AFTER** the callback function has been closed. After the `response` is availble inside the callback function and not outside. So, just put it inside the callback function.

```
function callback(response, status) {

    if (status !== "OK") {
        alert("Error with distance matrix");
        return;
    }
    console.log(response);
    let routes = response.rows[0].elements;
    const leastseconds = 86400; // 24 hours
    let drivetime = "";
    let closest = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
    const routeseconds = routes[i].elements[0].duration.value;
        if (routeseconds > 0 && routeseconds < leastseconds) {
                leastseconds = routeseconds; // this route is the shortest (so far)
                drivetime = routes[i].elements[0].duration.text; // hours and minutes
                closest = response.originAddresses[i]; // city name from destinations
        }
    }
    alert("The closest location is " + closest + " (" + drivetime + ")");
}
```

Comment: Very useful so far on the `callback function`. However, the code is still broken with error `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` and `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: response is not defined`

Comment: can u add a little bit what `response` looks like?

Comment: `console.log(response)` sends out the desired output
```
{
  distance: {
    text: "647 km",
    value: 647309
  },
  duration: {
    text: "11 hours 10 mins",
    value: 40220
  },
  status: "OK"
}
‘’’
The callback function is not working. When I run the code with the loop function included inside the callback function, I get the error, 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`
And,
`40 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at initMap 
    at js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap:160

Comment: I can see that code is ok as same kinda code is there in the doc as well https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_parsing_the_results

Comment: just make sure your for loop is proper checking the data that is coming as response.